# How to check symmetric space is locally symmetric space?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

**Definition** Riemannian manifold $\mathcal M$ is **symmetric** if $\forall x\in \mathcal M$, there exist an isometric $\varphi: \mathcal M \to \mathcal M$, such that for any $\gamma$  geodesic satisfying $\gamma (0)=x$, $\forall t \in \text{Dom}(\gamma) $, we have $\varphi(\gamma(t))= \gamma(-t)$.

**Definition** Let $R$ be the curvatural tensor of Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, we say $\mathcal M$ is **loally symmetric** if $DR=0$.

And locally symmetric space has an equivalent description as follows: for any piecewisely smooth **curve** (needn't geodesic) $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathcal M$, and any unit orthogonal tangent vectors $e_1, e_2 \in T_{\gamma(0)} \mathcal M$, the sectional curvature $K(e_1,e_2) = K(P_\gamma (e_1), P_\gamma (e_2))$, where $P_\gamma $ is the parallel movement along $\gamma$.

Then how can we check that if $\mathcal M$ is symmetric space, then it is locally symmetric space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is symmetric and $x \in \mathcal{M}$. Consider $s_x$ the symmetry at $x$, that is
$$
s_x(\exp_x(tv)) = \exp_x(-tv)
$$
It is an isometry by definition of symmetric space. Thus, $R$ is invariant under the action of $s_x$,. Now, one can show this general lemma: every $(r,s)$ tensor with $r+s$ odd that is invariant under $s_x$, is zero at $x$.

Apply this lemma to $\nabla R$, this will show that $(\nabla R)_x = 0$.